# How to collect data from two different routes/urls then at the end use the collected data to post a request to the server?

Tags: html, node.js, url, post, get

Lets assume that i have a URL `http://localhost:3000/choose1` which will provide the user with different choices to choose from, after the user choose he will be redirected to `http://localhost:3000/choose2` to choose another thing and then at the end i want to collect these choices upon it i will do a post request to the server.

So my question is what are the approaches to store these choices and forward it to the next URLs?

I am using `expressJS`

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to achieve what you want:

1. using functions as middleware     for example: `app.get('/custom/route/',functions1(req,res,next),function2(req,res,next),function3(req,res,next),..);`
2. using [request](https://github.com/request/request) library you can combine as many you want

personally, i will prefer the first one

Comment: Sorry i did not get how the first option works. Would it be something like this?
app.get('/choose1',function1(req,res,next){
 var choose1 = req.query;
},function2(req,res,next){
var choose2 = req.query;
next();
});

Could you write it for me knowing that there must be 2 URLs not just one?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the the options on a multi step form (where the options are separated by JS on thefrontend). Then you only make need to make one submission at the end. This also means you only need one route to handle everything. Here is an example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp